# Some aspx controls are not recognized in the code-behind files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, asp.net

I noticed that some aspx controls were not being recognized by intellisense, and when I tried to compile, I got errors stating that the controls basically didn't exist.

After a lot of tinkering, I realized that the .aspx.designer.cs file was missing for several .aspx files.

What is the best way to re-create the files?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Delete the aspx.designer.cs file
2. Right click on the aspx file and
   select "Convert to Web Application"

If the aspx.designer.cs file is already gone just do step 2.  If it's there but you are getting the error you described do both steps.

It's a total pain, hoping MS will get this one ironed out.  In my experience this occasionally happens if you make changes in the aspx file while you are running the application, so you might try to avoid that...

Comment: True, but maybe research the differences between "Web Site" and "Web Application" before taking that decision. There are pros and cons to both. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730880(VS.80).aspx